# How to save a rank column in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL.
I have tried this and managed to get a rank column.

```
SELECT  *,
    @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
    FROM patients p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
    ORDER BY ntx;
```

I have two questions:
1) How can I save the rank column permanently to the database?
2) How can I create another column named rank2 and save it to the database as well?
Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to "save" the rank column? If you can calculate it and display it using a query that's far simpler than saving data twice is it not?

Comment: @ScottMcGready, agreed, it's redundant, but one might legitimately do this to support an indexed search for a particular rank value or range of values.

Comment: @BillKarwin Perhaps but from the askers own admission, I doubt that would be needed at this stage. But fair play.

Comment: Scott, thanks for your comment. At first I was unable to understand it. After I read Bill's suggestions (and only after that), your view was made clear to me. I am now using the result set without saving anything.

Comment: You're welcome. The important thing to note here is that we're both right, it's just the circumstances that change. In your case, it's fine to display the data dynamicly. In others, you might wish to use bill's solution. The point is that you're learning from guys like us that have done it a million times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE patients ADD COLUMN rank INT UNSIGNED;

SET @curRank = 0;

UPDATE patients SET rank = @curRank := @curRank+1
ORDER BY ntx;
```

Though I would call this a "row number" not a "rank." A rank can have ties.

You can do create more columns if you want other ways to order the row numbering.

The risk of storing this data persistently is that it's hard to keep maintained.

- What if you insert a new row? You'd have to calculate its row number (possibly more than one if you have multiple columns for row number), and it might end up in the middle with respect to other rows, so you'd have to renumber other rows that should be higher.
- What if you delete an existing row? This also requires renumbering any rows that were numbered higher.

In both cases of renumbering, you have to think about concurrency. How do you prevent multiple clients from doing the renumbering at the same time and messing up each other's numbering? To be sure to solve this, you'd have to lock the whole table.

This might be no big deal in your application if you never have multiple clients doing this at the same time, but experienced database programmers try to avoid such cases.

Comment: Bill, thank you very much for your help and insightful comments. I will keep that in mind.